# How to extend the Generator class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I tried to filter a generator and had the expectation that this kind of general functionality must be defined anywhere in JavaScript, because it is defined for Arrays, but I can not find it. So I tried to define it. But I can not extend the built-in generators.

I have an example generator

```
function make_nums ()
{
  let nums = {};
  nums[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  };
  return nums;
}
```

generating some numbers.

```
[...make_nums()] // => Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

If I build an array, I can filter the array by the use of the `filter` function for arrays.

```
[...make_nums()].filter(n => n > 1) // => Array [ 2, 3 ]
```

But I do not want to build an array. Instead I want to take the old generator and build a new filtering generator. For this I wrote the following function.

```
function filtered (generator, filter)
{
  let g = {};
  g[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (let value of generator)
      if (filter(value))
        yield value;
  };
  return g;
}
```

which can be used to do what I want.

```
[...filtered (make_nums(), n => n > 1)] // => Array [ 2, 3 ]
```

But this is a very general function, which can be applied to every generator in the same way the `filter` function can be applied to every `Array`. So I tried to extend generators in general, but I do not understand how.

The MDN documentation for [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) suggests somehow that `Generator.prototype` may exist, but it does not seem to exist. When I try to define something in `Generator.prototype`, I get the error

> ReferenceError: Generator is not defined

How can I extend the built-in `Generator` class?

Comment: "*But this is a very general function*" - what's wrong with that?

Comment: Why would you want to extend `Generator`s when you could also extend [all iterators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%25iteratorprototype%25-object)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the traditional caveat that extending built-in prototypes is not necessarily the best idea, and that it's something to be done with caution, you can get the generator function prototype with

```
const genproto = Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){});
```

With that you could add a `filter()` capability:

```
Object.defineProperty(genproto, "filter", {
  value: function*(predicate) {
    for (let value of this())
      if (predicate(value)) yield value;
  }
});
```

And thus:

```
console.log([... function*() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) yield i;
  }.filter(value => value % 2 === 0)
]);
```

will print `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`.

To be clear: this answer is about extending the prototype for generator *functions*, not the generator objects themselves. Thus this will ensure that every generator function in the program can use that `.filter()` method and any other similar extension.

Comment: OP wants to extend `Generator`, not `GeneratorFunction`

Comment: @Bergi well I could not figure out how to make sense of that; you may be right however. This is something I'd never thought of but it does seem kind-of useful once I forgive myself for extending that prototype object. Things like `.take()` etc are really easy to implement.

Comment: Just change `getPrototypeOf(function*(){})` to `getPrototypeOf(function*(){}())` and `this()` to `this`.

Comment: @Bergi well sure, but what I meant was that the generator object itself doesn't necessarily inherit from that prototype; the iterable/iterator protocols are just that: protocols. Thus it wouldn't be possible to know that a given generator object would have the extended capabilities. But maybe I'm missing something; it makes my head hurt a little.

Comment: [This diagram](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-generatorfunction-objects) may help (probably both to clarify, and to make your head hurt even more :P). All generator objects (created by calling a generator function) do inherit from `GeneratorPrototype` and `IteratorPrototype`.

Comment: @Bergi right, I get that. And I think I was wrapped around a sort-of bogus concern that "home-made" generators would make code fragile; they would, but I don't think making home-made generators is a very good idea in the first place. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that I was confused about `Generator` and `Iterable`. I thought I had to extend `Generator`, but it is actually sufficient to extend `Iterable`. And the fact that `Iterable` does not seem to be defined by JavaScript either, makes it easy to define it, to avoid problems with modifications of built-in prototypes.

This actually does what I tried to achieve.

```
class Iterable {
  constructor (generator) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = generator;
  }
}

Iterable.prototype.filter = function (predicate) {
  let iterable = this;
  return new Iterable (function* () {
    for (let value of iterable)
      if (predicate (value))
        yield value;
  });
};
```

I can create `Iterables`

```
make_nums = new Iterable(function* () { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; });
```

can use them

```
[...make_nums] // => Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

and can filter them

```
[...make_nums.filter(n => n > 1)] // => Array [ 2, 3 ]
```