# Filter and map functions for generators

Tags: javascript, generator

What is the recommended approach in JavaScript to passing around generators that include filtering + mapping logic?

Somehow, JavaScript generators are missing such fundamental things as `filter` and `map` operands, similar to arrays, to be able to create a generator that includes that logic, without having to run the iteration first.

My head-on approach was to implement custom functions that apply the logic:

```js
function * filter(g, cb) {
    let a;
    do {
        a = g.next();
        if (!a.done && cb(a.value)) {
            yield a.value;
        }
    } while (!a.done);
    return a.value;
}

function * map(g, cb) {
    let a;
    do {
        a = g.next();
        if (!a.done) {
            yield cb(a.value);
        }
    } while (!a.done);
    return a.value;
}
```

But this creates a callback hell. I want to simply chain a generator, like a regular array:

```js
// create a filtered & re-mapped generator, without running it:
const gen = myGenerator().filter(a => a > 0).map(b => ({value: b})); 

// pass generator into a function that will run it:
processGenerator(gen);
```

Is there a way to extend generators to automatically have access to such basic functions?

As an extra, if somebody wants to weight in on why such fundamental things aren't part of the generators implementation, that'll be awesome! I would think that filtering and mapping are the two most essential things one needs for sequences.

**UPDATE**

This all ended with me writing my own [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library :)

Comment: Looks like there is a proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers currently on stage 2

Comment: There are also links to some npm packages that might implement some of desired functionality

Comment: @skyboyer That looks interesting. I wonder though, if there is any polyfill to use it today, and not years from now :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend the Generator class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534156/how-to-extend-the-generator-class)

Comment: Following question is dealing with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534156/how-to-extend-the-generator-class

Comment: I saw that question before I asked here. It has a more narrow focus, while the two answers are no good. I tried the accepted answer, it doesn't really work. And the author's answer - that's for Iterators strictly.

Comment: Do you care about generators (and their `.next(value)`, `.return()` and `.throw()` methods and return values) specifically, or only about iterators in general?

Comment: @vitaly-t FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68254834/turning-rxjs-observable-into-an-asynchronous-iterable

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to your solution would be to use the `for...of` loop instead of a `do...while`.

I would also prefer the `filter` and `map` functions to consume and produce a generator function like below :

```js
function filter(gen, predicate) {
  return function*() {
    for (let e of gen()) {
       if (predicate(e)) {
         yield e; 
       }
     }
  }
}

function map(gen, fn) {
  return function*() {
    for (let e of gen()) {
      yield fn(e);
    }
  }
}

function generatorWrapper(gen) {
  return {
    call: () => gen(),
    filter: predicate => generatorWrapper(filter(gen, predicate)),
    map: fn => generatorWrapper(map(gen, fn))
  };
}

function* generator() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

const it = generatorWrapper(generator)
  .filter(x => x > 1)
  .map(x => x * 2)
  .call();

for (let e of it) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: It may improve implementation of the custom operands, but it does not solve the chaining problem, which is what the question all about. Your solution still relies on nested callbacks,  just in a different way.

Comment: As `filter` and `map` are not provided by default, you would need to use a wrapper if you want to chain the operations. I updated my answer

Comment: We can wrap a generator in many different ways, and those will all be work-arounds, rather than proper solutions. You then have to remember to wrap every call for generators.

Comment: b.t.w. your implementations of `map` and `filter` are not quite complete, they also must return the last value, pass the sequence, because this is how the default generator works. Otherwise, your custom handlers lose the return value.

Comment: "*I prefer to consume and produce a generator function*" - I don't see any advantage there. But if you do this, you should pass through arguments to the generator function.

Comment: @vitaly-t Passing values to `.next()` doesn't really work for `filter`. If you wanted to use this functionality, you'd need to specify explicitly how it should work. And it gets even more complicated for `flatMap`.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I implemented my own approach to extending existing iterators, so they can be used in place of the original ones, which makes things easier, as I no longer need to wrap them into anything. See my answer.

Comment: `I no longer need to wrap them into anything`, with your solution, you need to call `Iterable.extend(test)` so it's quite the same as using a `wrapper` ? This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534339/5521607) might be a better one

Answer (score 1):

I may have figured out a proper solution to this...

I created class `Iterable`, which extends on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534156/how-to-extend-the-generator-class):

```
class Iterable {
    constructor(generator) {
        this[Symbol.iterator] = generator;
    }

    static extend(generator, cc) {
        // cc - optional calling context, when generator is a class method;
        return function () {
            return new Iterable(generator.bind(cc ?? this, ...arguments));
        }
    }
}

Iterable.prototype.filter = function (predicate) {
    let iterable = this;
    return new Iterable(function* () {
        for (let value of iterable)
            if (predicate(value)) {
                yield value;
            }
    });
};

Iterable.prototype.map = function (cb) {
    let iterable = this;
    return new Iterable(function* () {
        for (let value of iterable) {
            yield cb(value);
        }
    });
};
```

Now we can take an existing generator function, like this:

```
function* test(value1, value2) {
    yield value1;
    yield value2;
}
```

and turn it into an extended iterator:

```
const extTest = Iterable.extend(test);
```

and then use it in place of the original generator:

```
const i = extTest(111, 222).filter(f => f > 0).map(m => ({value: m}));
```

This now works correctly:

```
const values = [...i];
//=> [ { value: 111 }, { value: 222 } ]
```

## UPDATE

In the end of all this, I wrote my own [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library.

Comment: I think you should better distinguish between iterators, generators and generator functions. `test` is not an iterator (not even iterable).

Comment: It is well distinguished now. I was still refactoring my answer when you posted it.

Comment: Nothing in the code changed since I posted my comment. I'm nitpicking on calling a `.bind()` method on iterators - they only have `.next()` (and optionally `.return`/`.throw`)

Comment: That was renamed into `generator`, because that's what it is.

Comment: Just now, yes. But no, it's not a generator - it's a generator *function*.

Comment: Those terms are mostly interchangeable :) Good enough for an argument name anyhow :)

Comment: Btw I think you should `.bind(this, ...arguments)`, not use the function itself as the this value.

Comment: That's not right. The context must be the generator itself, not the wrap function context. No? :)

Comment: @Bergi Anyway, I made method `extend` better, after some testing here ;)

Comment: Oh, I had not heard about IxJS. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: I think my thing to turn a RxJS Observable into an asynchronous iterable is working now. Now you can first convert any iterable into an Observable with RxJS from(), then do the manipulations within pipe(), then convert the resulting Observable back into an iterable and then iterate through it with "for await". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68254834/turning-rxjs-observable-into-an-asynchronous-iterable

Answer (score 1):

How about a pipelining function that will take the original iterable and yield values through pipelined decorators?

```js
const pipe = function* (iterable, decorators) {
  // First build the pipeline by iterating over the decorators
  // and applying them in sequence.
  for(const decorator of decorators) {
    iterable = decorator(iterable)
  }

  // Then yield the values of the composed iterable.
  for(const value of iterable) {
    yield value;
  }
};

const filter = predicate =>
  function* (iterable) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      if (predicate(value)) {
        yield value;
      }
    }
  };

const map = cb =>
  function* (iterable) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      yield cb(value);
    }
  };

const mergeMap = cb =>
  function* (iterable) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      for (const mapped of cb(value)) {
        yield mapped;
      }
    }
  };

const take = n =>
  function* (iterable) {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      if (!n--) {
        break;
      }
      yield value;
    }
  };

function* test(value1, value2) {
  yield value1;
  yield value2;
}

function* infinite() {
  for (;;) yield Math.random();
}

for (const value of pipe(test(111, 222), [
  filter(f => f > 0),
  map(m => ({ value: m }))
])) {
  console.log(value);
}

for (const value of pipe(infinite(), [
  take(5),
  mergeMap(v => [v, { timesTwo: v * 2 }])
])) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```